# I want to compare two least-squares algorithms. One provides lower CI than the other, but not always. How do you compare?

Tags: confidence-interval, weighted-regression

I am trying to compare two weighing schemes of a least-squares fit for several datasets (about 100). I can calculate the confidence intervals and the sigma values of the parameters (a,b,c). I compare the ratioA = sigma_a_new/sigma_a_old. I have about 100 such ratios for the 3 parameters. If the ratios are all <1, then the new weighing scheme works.

Is there a better way to put this that's mathematically/statistically more sound?